# How to add a part of a line (for every line in a file) at the end of the line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have stored coordinates in a table like this:

```
140.7 44.9,140.7 44.7,141.0 44.7,141.1 44.8
...
```

How can I copy the first to values `140.7 44.9` (plus one comma) to the end of the line so that this will be a closed polygon?

```
140.7 44.9,140.7 44.7,141.0 44.7,141.1 44.8, 140.7 44.9
```

Can this be achieved in one command, or do I have to grep the first part and then append this to the other lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this awk one-liner:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{print $0,$1}' file
```

change into `OFS=", "` if you love that whithspace after the last comma.

Comment: So both of you were really fast but you were the first with the awk solution.

Comment: @StefanB. this is an easy job for awk.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
s='140.7 44.9,140.7 44.7,141.0 44.7,141.1 44.8'
sed -r 's/([^,]+)(.*)/\0,\1/' <<< "$s"
140.7 44.9,140.7 44.7,141.0 44.7,141.1 44.8, 140.7 44.9
```

Using awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=', ' '{print $0, $1}' <<< "$s"
140.7 44.9,140.7 44.7,141.0 44.7,141.1 44.8, 140.7 44.9
```

Comment: This looks simpler `sed -r 's/([^,]+)(.*)/\0,\1/'`

Comment: Thanks so much, I edited my sed command. sed is handy here for in line editing of the file.